# Classifying app reviews into useful categories

Tags: classification, natural-language

I have a dataset which consists of Google Play app reviews for one app. I'm currently having a unbalanced

**Dataset categorization**
The dataset is basically text, in which the user is asked to provide information about the app. Most of these reviews are short texts, mean of 35 +/- 59 characters. I have 100k of labelled examples. Also, about 80% of them are compliments, most are really small (e.g. great app). 17% are complaints. And then I have 2 % that are composed of 4 other classes.

**Feature extraction**
I've tried TF-IDF, CountVectorizer and Doc2Vec. First two are provided by SkLearn, the last one is from by Gensim. All of them seems to have similar performance. But CountVectorizer is somewhat best. I'm using a ngram range of (1,2).

**Feature reduction**
I've tried using SVD with dimension of 500, 200 and 1000.

**Results**
I'm getting a pretty decent weighted f1-score: 0.80 but a mediocre average f1-score: 0.10.

Are there any obvious things I should do to